# Recyclerview not reloading data when notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am using recycler view in my application. I am initialising the adapter and recycler view inside onActivity Created as given below,

```
adapter = new CardsRecyclerAdapterInternal(WalletStoreFragment.this);
        cardSummaryList = new ArrayList<LoyaltyCardSummary>();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Now I am calling an API to load data for the recycler view. Here is my hierarchy

Fragment --> Fragment presenter --> API Layer

So my fragment invokes a method in presenter which in turns calls the API. The API returns data back to the presenter. I am using EventBus for that.

The fragment implements an interface given below,

```
public interface StoreView
    {
        void reloadCardList (List<CardSummary> cards);
        void dismissCardLoad();
    }
```

Presenter calls the interface method to reload the recycler view data, using the code given below.

```
@Override
    public void reloadCardList(final List<CardSummary> cards)
    {
        cardSummaryList.clear();
        cardSummaryList.addAll(cards);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.invalidate();
    }
```

Here is the code for adapter

```
public class CardsRecyclerAdapterInternal extends
            RecyclerView.Adapter<CardsRecyclerAdapterInternal.ViewHolder>
    {

        private Fragment frag;

        public CardsRecyclerAdapterInternal()
        {
            //this.frag = _frag;
        }

        public void setCardSummaryList(List<CardSummary> cards)
        {
            //this.cardSummaryList = cards;
        }


        @Override
        public CardsRecyclerAdapterInternal.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            // Inflate the custom layout
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallet_store_item, parent, false);

            // Return a new holder instance
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CardsRecyclerAdapterInternal.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            CardSummary card = cardSummaryList.get(position);
            holder.txt_CardName.setText(card.getCardName());
            holder.txt_CardCategory.setText(card.getCardCategory());
            String cardURL = Global.CARD_IMAGE + Uri.encode(card.getCardImage());
            Glide
                    .with(WalletStoreFragment.this)
                    .load(cardURL)
                    .into(holder.cardImage);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return cardSummaryList.size();
        }

        public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView txt_CardName;
            TextView txt_CardCategory;
            ImageView cardImage;

            public ViewHolder(View convertView) {
                super(convertView);
                txt_CardName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_CardName);
                txt_CardCategory = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_CardCategory);
                cardImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_CardImage);


            }
        }
    }
```

But this is not reloading the data in recycler view. Not even calling the getItemCount() inside the recycler view. Whats going wrong here?

****************************Update************************

I have more inputs to my issue. I am having a tabbed view pager aplication, and the recycler view is loaded from one of the tabs when a button is clicked. If I directly load the recycler view fragment in main TabPage everything works fine, but when its inside another view the recycler is not reloading. Here is how I load the new fragment,

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment = new StoreFragment();
                manager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack("STORE_FRAGMENT")
                        .commit();
```

and here is my container within the XML file,

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please show the code for your `CardsRecyclerAdapterInternal` class. I am not sure if you have declared a List<CardSummary> as one of its members (adapter then holds location of this in memory) - so that when you add/set new list, you update this field (the underlying dataset).

Comment: please check the updated question. Thanks

Comment: do you ever call `setCardSummaryList` ?

Comment: I was using this before when the adapter was in a different class file. Now I have teh adapter in same class as the fragment. So i am not using it. The cardSummaryList array is global to the fragment.

Comment: That is in general a bad idea as I'm very against non-static inner classes in Android. But as you said, not even `getCount()` gets called, so I ask: did you put a `Log.` inside `reloadCardList`? Are you sure the API is returning?

Comment: I was initially using an external class, but as it was not working I moved that inside the fragment. Yes the API is returning back data. The getItemCount() is called the very first time when the adapter is initialised. But not when new data is added. Thanks

Comment: could you spla the complete class in a gist (https://gist.github.com/)? I'm sure there's some small detail missing. PS.: There's no need to call `recyclerView.invalidate()`

Answer (score 0):

The variable (List) `cardSummaryList`is not declared anywhere in the Adapter class. So the `cardSummaryList.size();` won't return anything and if at all it should raise NullPointerException.
You need change your Adapter code by: including a local variable `List<CardSummary> cardSummaryList;` and then create a constructor that takes a List as one of its argument -

```
private List<CardSummary> cardSummaryList;
....
public CardsRecyclerAdapterInternal(List<CardSummary> cardsList)
{
 cardSummaryList = cardsList;
}
```

you should also add a method that updates your list (call it something like `reloadCards(List<CardSummary> cards)` and then the body of this method is something like:

```
public void reloadCards(List<CardSummary> cards){ 
    cardSummaryList.clear();       
    cardSummaryList.addAll(cards);
}
```

Finally, you then change your `reloadCardList(final List<CardSummary> cards)` code into:

```
public void reloadCardList(final List<CardSummary> cards)
    {        
        adapter.reloadCards(cards);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.invalidate();
    }
```

Please give it a try and let me know if this helps you resolve your problem.
By the way, please look at an example of [how to use RecyclerView](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) - you can also look at the tutorial here on [Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)